# How to convert string type variable to user defined class type variable

Tags: java, variables

I have a  text file , I am reading that text file and fetching some value from there, I am getting those value as string type. I have class that expects value of its type, this means I have to pass those strings which I am fetching from the text file by converting to my or better to say user defined class type. I am not able to convert the string to user defined class type. I am developing my code in core java. please suggest me how to convert this.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert" a string to class? You need to provide some more context, example of your class, and better definition of what you are talking about. You also don't seem to have done much research into it yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by converting String to class type ?

Comment: There are some existing solution for various formats (xml, json, csv). Please tell us, if the text file has a "standard" structure. (or show an example)

Comment: -1 for a very lousy and imprecise question, which in its current form is impossible to answer with other than guesses.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this :

```
Class A {
   A(String str)
   {
      this.word = str;
   }
   private String word;
}
```

And then pass the objects of A, which will have the string values in the field.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're describing a form of *parsing*. You probably want to look into so called *parser generators*.

A parser translates text to objects (which seems to be what you need) and a parser generator takes as input a description of how to construct the objects from strings, and generates a parser accordingly.

A few examples I've used my self:

- [JavaCup](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/) (which is compatible with [JFLex](http://jflex.de/))
- [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)

Answer (score 1):

so you have a string and want to make an object of it?

for example you read the string into input_String;
can't you just give that string to the constructor of the class?

```
String input_String = textScanner.readLine() //or something like that
myObject = ClassToInstantiate(input_String);
```

or am I not getting the question right?